# Access to location arrow in SDK

Tags: iphone, core-location

Simple question, the little arrow that is used for the Apple's find your current location icon. Do you have access to that icon in the SDK as a UIBarButtonSystemItem or something similar? Looked through the doco and its not a UIBarButtonSystemItem as far as I could see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to make my own, doesn't seem to be a way.